# html over-line with Greek letters

Tags: html, diacritics, entities

Macrons and overlines do not align properly with Greek letters.
In the following code, the tilde (&#771) will be placed properly above the pi (or any Greek letter), but the next two marks will not ('p' is used for comparison), shifted to the right instead. Lambda shows the extreme nature of the problem, making an *anti-Lambda* (in particle physics) appear like a *Lambda-minus*

```html
&pi;&#771; &nbsp; p&#771;<br/>
&pi;&#772; &nbsp; p&#772;<br/>
&pi;&#773; &nbsp; p&#773;<br/>
&Lambda;&#773; &nbsp; L&#773;<br/>
```

π̃   p̃
π̄   p̄
π̅   p̅
Λ̅   L̅

[screen shot: detail of problem with Greek diacritics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN437.png)

Anyone knows how to fix this issue using characters and entities only i.e. without *span* or *LaTex*?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: How are you displaying this HTML? Which browser, font, etc? I see the problem in your screenshot but the Stack Overflow app for Android is displaying the overbars just fine for me here.

Comment: Chrome, Firefox, Edge (in W10): all show the same problem.  Setting font to Calibri makes the problem less dramatic, but still not correct.

Comment: Tested it with 15 fonts in Chrome:  Arial, Helvetica, Times New Roman, Times, Courier New, Courier, Verdana, Georgia, Palatino, Garamond, Bookman, Comic Sans MS, Trebuchet MS, Arial Black Impact -  all show the same issue

Comment: still weirder: samsung galaxy/android, stack exchange app: the overbars (&#773;) are not displaying at all (as suggested e.g. on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline), neither over 'pi' nor 'p'

Comment: using https://wordmark.it/, the only acceptable rendition of Lambda-bar uses Cambria Math (serif), or Lucida Sans Unicode (sans).  Curious...

Answer (score 0):

Here are the results (cambria math / Lucida Sans Unicode)

```html
<style>
 .serif {font-family: 'cambria math';}
 .sans {font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode';}
</style>

<p class='serif'>&pi;&#773; &nbsp; p&#773; &nbsp; &Lambda;&#773; &nbsp; L&#773;</p>
<p class='sans'>&pi;&#773; &nbsp; p&#773; &nbsp; &Lambda;&#773; &nbsp; L&#773;</p>
```